# What does the 'SHARE' port on the usb expansion card do?

Tags: usb

[image: Share port]

So here is an old USB card I installed in a desktop.  The two ports on the right work fine - when I plug in a USB peripheral it is recognised immediately.

The port on the right (labelled 'SHARE') apparently does nothing.  When I plug in a USB peripheral it is not recognised by the Windows 7 OS.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this normal?
2. What does SHARE mean in this context?
3. Is there anything I can do to take advantage of this port?

The card is connected to a USB2 9-pin connector on the motherboard just like the usb ports on the front of the PC.

I have tried looking this up online but whenever you type 'share' and 'usb' in the same search you just get a lot of explanations of how to share across networks, which is not what I want to do.

Edit:  You can see the 4 pins here and they are not connected - this must be why it is not functional.  There is no 4 pin connection on the motherboard, so I assume that means it cannot be connected up?

[image]

Comment: What is the make and model of the card?

Comment: Weird.  If you don't know the make and model - can you run PCI-Z (https://www.pci-z.com/) on this system and include a screenshot of the first screen?

Comment: Wait ... if it's connected to the 9-pin connector on your motherboard - then this is not an expansion card - it's simply the ports on a bracket.  An expansion card would actually plug into the PCI-E port connector on the motherboard.  Are all ports on the bracket connected to that 9-pin connector?  Did this come with your motherboard?  If so, tell us the make and model of your motherboard ---- As far as what I mean by "ports on a bracket" - here is something similar: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31p2d9R-LFL.jpg

Comment: @DavidPostill It is an ASUS USB3P - I will upload a picture.

Comment: @LawrenceC Ah, you are right - I was led astray by some sites calling the ASUS USB3P an expansion card (example: http://www.ebay.com/itm/ASUS-USB3P-3-Ports-USB-Expansion-PCI-Card-for-PC-/152036438864).

Comment: @LawrenceC The motherboard is MS-7336 V1.0 - HP tower originally with XP, so old!

Comment: More info from https://narcoticevil.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/asus-usb3p-revision-1-00-item-archive/: *A small expansion card to allow for 2 more USB devices and another port named ‘SHARE’. Has ‘FOR HOME OR OFFICE USE’ Printed on PCB. PCB can be detached from metal plate which allows for it to take up a PCI slot space. Has two pin connection sets,
9 pins on a white base named ‘USB2P’
4 pins on a black base named ‘USB1P′*

Comment: My guess is that the SHARE port is USB1P and is not connected to the motherboard through the 4-pin connector.

Comment: @clcto You are exactly right!  I think DavidPostill would have also been able to tell me that if I had been able to upload the picture of the card (ongoing iphone to windows image transfer problems) - It seems then that I need a 4 pin connector.  I cannot see a 4 pin connection on the motherboard tho...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is an ASUS USB3P

Looking at pictures of the card online it looks like two of the ports go to a 9-pin header and the remaining port goes to a 4-pin header.

If there is no cable on the 4-pin header then i'm pretty sure the port will do nothing. If there is a cable on the 4-pin header trace it and see where it goes.

Why it is labeled "share" I don't know for sure, maybe in the original intended configuration the port was "shared" with one of the front ports such that you could use one or the other but not both. Since I can't find any manual for this board I expect it was originally a pack-in accessory with some motherboard.

---

> There is no 4 pin connection on the motherboard, so I assume that means it cannot be connected up?

If you had a spare USB header you could probably build an adapter cable to hook it up. You would have to figure out the pin out but that is easy enough with a multi meter.

But from some googling it looks like your motherboard doesn't have any spare USB headers so short of using a USB PCI card with an internal header or using an internal USB hub I don't see any real options for hooking it up.

Comment: Yes, you can see in the new picture the 4 pins are not connected, and I cannot see an appropriate place to connect them on the motherboard...  Any suggestions?  I cannot find the manual either.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the 9 pin connector can handle only two USB ports so I'm thinking that the SHARE indicates an only power port, used to power old external hard disks that had two USB connectors to get enough current. You can try to charge your phone on that port, it should work.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but my phone does not charge on that port.  It charges from the other two ports but not from 'SHARE'.

Comment: Oh okay, I quote plugwash answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is an old post, but I've found my way here looking up answers for exacyly the same PCB, it seems that if you google USB1P what you get is a reference to a keyboard, so adding 2+2 may just give us an internal keyboard connector, from whichever motherboard this curio originated from, so it has two perfectly good USB ports, plus a keyboard-only connector which is now obsolete, at least that's what I'm taking it for, not looking anymore.